# In an expect script, how do I remove a set of special characters from a string variable?

Tags: tcl, expect

Say I have a variable that is set to some user input. I have no control over what the user will enter.

How would I go about removing all characters that are not in [A-Za-z0-9], spaces, periods, or commas?

```
proc getUserInput {} {
    set timeout 60
    send_user "\nEnter user input: "
    expect_user {
        -re "(.*)\n" {
            set userInput $expect_out(1,string)
        }
        timeout {
            exitTimeout "Timed out waiting for user input!"
        }
    }
    return $userInput
}

set rawValue [ getUserInput ]
// massage variable goes here?
set massagedValue "$rawValue"
```

Not sure if it matters, but I'm using expect 5.45.

```
$ expect -v
expect version 5.45
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Expect` is a `Tcl` extension so you can use all `Tcl` commands when writing `Expect` scripts. You can try this in `tclsh`:

```
% set v1 "###the string###"
###the string###
% set v2 [regsub -all {[^ .,[:alnum:]]} $v1 ""]
the string
%
```